# Do i want to include Testdevice id in admob to use my app in my android mobile?

Tags: android, admob

Iam new to android development ... I recently added admob in my android application. I will also use my app in my mobile, i removed the testdevice id and uploaded in google play....

Code :

```
AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
.build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

1) if i use my app now, will it be lead to any account deactivation for those impressions or can i use it without any problem??

or should i want to add the testdevice id to use in my mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your app without any problem. However, to prevent click fraud which leads to account suspension, make sure you don't click on the ads multiple times. The test device id, as the name suggests is solely for testing purposes during the development phase, so once your app goes live, you can remove the test device ids and use it like any normal user would.